# Call javascript onsubmit nao "prende" o submit até dar a confirmação de eiliminação

Tags: javascript, html

Deparo-me com o seguinte erro:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="sweetalert(1)">
            Dados aqui !!!

            <input type="button" id="selectall-game-button" label="check all" value="Selecionar tudo">
            <input type="submit" id="delete-game-button" value="Eliminar" style="display:none;"/>
```

**JS**

```
function sweetalert(x) {
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            swal({
                title: "Aviso!",
                text: "Tens a certeza que queres apagar este/s ficheiro/s?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Sim, eliminar!",
                cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            }, function(isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal("Eliminado!", "O/s ficheiro/s foi/foram eliminado/s!", "success");
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelado", "A operação foi cancelada, os ficheiros foram salvos!", "error");
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Já testei apenas com o alert and confirm no onsubmit e deu tudo certo. Mas ao colocar este script no `onsubmit` ele nao "prende" a função, apaga logo os dados antes de confirmar se quero ou nao apagar o ficheiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo basico.

HTML:

```
 <a href="delete.php?id=45454"  onClick="return confirm_delete('John');">
 <img src="../../../images/icones/effacer.png" border="0" alt="Deletar">
 </a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 function confirm_delete(msg)
 {
     var msg_total;
     if (msg == '')
     {
        msg_total = msg_glb_delete_start + "\n" + msg_glb_delete_end;
     }
     else
     {
        msg_total = msg_glb_delete_start + "\n( " + msg + " )\n"+ msg_glb_delete_end;
     }

     ret = confirm(msg_total);
     return ret;

 }

 msg_glb_delete_start = "Tem certeza que deseja apagar este registro?";
 msg_glb_delete_end = "Esta operação é definitiva. Clique em OK para continuar.";
```

De outro jeito, se vc quere usar obrigatoriamente sweetalert, falta coisas no seu codigo:
vc tem:

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="sweetalert(1)">
```

quando o codigo deve ser:

```
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="sweetalert(); return false;">
```

Falta ; e falta a valor "return false". Provavelmente isso é o problema.

Comment: O objectivo era fazer isto: http://jsfiddle.net/7whfdcs5/ com aquele alert .. é possivel?

Comment: Fiz a edição da resposta, esperando que isso vai ajudar vc.

Comment: Continua a nao dar, ele mal dou o Submit, elimina a/as linha/as da base de dados..

Comment: Vc coloquei o return false? Outro ponto, no seu navegador, usa a fermenta "Desenvolvedor Web" (se vc usa Firefox) para abrir a "console" e ver erro Javascript. Porque em muito caso, quando o JS encontra um erro, ele continua sem cuidar do resto do código. Então vc pode ter um erro numa outra parte do seu código o que faz que a sua função não e executada.

Comment: Siim, coloquei.. O unico erro que dá é este: http://prntscr.com/5zb1tl

Comment: Não seria um problema com a versão da biblioteca que vc esta usando?

Comment: Creio que o problema esteja mesmo na altura que em que eu faço submit, **ATUALIZEI O CÓDIGO PARA PERCEBER**

Comment: Ja consegui, tinha um erro no meu codigo `onsubmit="sweetalert(1);" return false;"`  -> `onsubmit="sweetalert(1); return false"`

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode usar `onsubmit="sweetalert(1)"`. O único jeito de esperar um retorno booleano no `onsubmit` é usando o `confirm` nativo (feio e confuso), que é síncrono (o que quer dizer que ele "prende" o fluxo do código, como você disse).

Você precisa colocar uma chamada de função intermediária ali, cancelar o submit e aguardar a interação para, se for o caso, submeter manualmente. Algo assim:

```
<form id="meuForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="sweetalert(1); return false;">
```

E lá na sua `function(isConfirm){` você pega o form e submete se passar na sua verificação:

```
document.getElementById('meuForm').submit();
```

<sub>Nota: aquele `switch` na sua função é totalmente desnecessário, pode eliminar.</sub>

Comment: Nao funcionou .. :ss Pode fazer um Jsfiddle se faz favor?

Comment: @thecreator http://jsfiddle.net/7whfdcs5/. Mas não dá tempo de mostrar o aviso de que os ficheiros foram eliminados, o form é submetido antes. Se quiser evitar que a página recarregue, precisa usar ajax em vez de submeter o formulário (o que seria o tema de uma pergunta à parte, caso tenha dúvidas sobre como fazer).

Comment: Continua a nao dar, no seu exemplo tudo funciona como pretendo, mas aqui nao **atualizei o codigo**

Comment: Ja consegui, tinha um erro no meu codigo `onsubmit="sweetalert(1);" return false;"`  -> `onsubmit="sweetalert(1); return false"`